# In polar coordinates, is the radial vector direction undefined?

Tags: vectors

If I specify a radial vector R in cylindrical or polar coordinates, the direction is undefined, unlike an x or y vector, where the direction is fixed.

How would I specify $\vec{x} + \vec{y}$ in polar coordinates? Would I just say $\vec{r}$? How do I specify the angle in conjunction with the radius in terms of elementary operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$ we write the radial vector

$$\vec r=\hat xx+\hat yy=\hat \rho \rho$$

In spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$, we have

$$\vec r=\hat rr$$

The directions are embedded in the unit vectors $\hat \rho=\hat x\cos(\phi)+\hat y\sin(\phi)$ and $\hat r=\hat x\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\hat y\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\hat z\cos(\theta)$.  So, if we wish to be more explicit, we can write in polar coordinates

$$\vec r=\hat \rho(\phi)\rho \tag 1$$

and in spherical coordinates

$$\vec r =\hat r(\theta,\phi)r \tag 2$$

where in $(1)$, we see the functional dependence on $\phi$ appear in the unit vector $\hat \rho$ and in $(2)$ we see the functional dependence on $\theta$ and $\phi$ appear in the unit vector $
\hat r$.

Comment: It depends on who reads it.  Any vector has a magnitude and direction.  So, the position vector does also.   The magnitude of the vector does not convey any information of the vector's direction.  And the unit vector contains information only on the direction of the vector.  In polar or spherical coordinates, the radial unit vector embeds the directional information through its dependence on the angular coordinate variables.

Comment: Ok I see thanks. I was confused because the unit vector gave information on direction, but unit vector of R has no direction. I see now that the unit vector of R must be given in terms of the angular coordinates.

Comment: Yes indeed.  For spherical coordinates, we have $$\hat r=\hat x\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\hat y\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\hat z\cos(\theta)$$